# While comparing two array's elements, the result returns incorrect value, why?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why does this code return 'false'? What am I doing wrong?

```js
var propertyValue = "4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128";
var input = "4, 16";
var arr1 = propertyValue.split(',');
var arr2 = input.split(',');
var result = arr1.indexOf(arr2) > -1;
console.log(result); // returns false, should return true because 4 and 16 is in arr1
```

Comment: `arr1` contains the elements `["4", " 8", " 16", " 32", " 64", " 128"]`. Non of those elements will ever equal to an array. (As a matter of fact, [nothing except the array itself will ever be equal to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript).)

Comment: You need to use `split(', ')` or `split(/,\s*/)` with a space after `,`

Comment: @adiga it still doesnt work, I dont understand...

Comment: That's ont the only change. Check the duplicate. You need to check: `var result = arr2.every(v => arr1.includes(v))` If every value in `arr2` is included in `arr1`